# Finding bijection between set of equivalence classes and integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations

Let $X = \Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ be the set of pairs of positive integers. Consider the equivalence relation
$(a, b) \sim (c, d)$, if $a + d = c + b$.

Prove that there is a bijection $F: X{/} \to \Bbb Z$, where $X{/}\sim$ is the set of equivalence classes.

I tried defining a function $g: X \to \Bbb Z$ such that $g(a,b) = a - b$ and showed this is surjective. But it fails infectivity test when changing the domain from $X$ to $X{/}\sim$. Could someone please help me define a bijective function between $X{/}\sim$ and $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: What's the motivation behind having $g(a,b) = a-b$? If you think about what this equivalence relation is, its pairs of number that sum to a given number, so your equivalence class is the sum! In other words, try the functino $g(a,b) = a+b$

Comment: My motivation for that was to get negative integers, as a,b are natural numbers so the only way to span the negatives would be to have some sort of subtraction.

Comment: Probably easier to show a bijection with the natural numbers themselves, and then use the fact that there’s a bijection between natural numbers and the integers, so you can compose them?

Comment: As in should I show that the set X/~ = { [2], [3], [4], [5], [6],...} is one-to-one with N as for any [a] in X we can take [a] and map it to a - 1 in N. And then show bijection between N and Z?

Comment: Are you sure the equivalence relation is not $(a,b)\sim (c,d) \iff a+d=b+c$? That is the more common definition.

Comment: Oh, my apologies. You are right - I missed that. I am still stuck however on finding a way to associate each integer to an element in X.

Comment: *Now* try your map.

Comment: My map works in associating elements of Z to X, but it fails for X/~ to Z, no?

Comment: Did you check with the correct definition of $\sim$, or just assume that it because it didn't work with the wrong definition, it also won't work with the correct one?

Comment: Would this reasoning be correct? Consider g: X -> Z such that g(a,b) = a-b. Here, g is surjective because for any Z, exists x of X such that g(x) = z. Namely, if z is negative, define x = (1, z+1) and if z positive x= (z+1, 1). Now, apply g on X/~ -> Z. Each equivalence class [x] of X/~ represents all tuples (a,b) such that a-b = x. Hence, g is also injective as for each [x],[y], g([x]) is not equal to g([y]). QED

Comment: Comments are not the place to ask whether a proposed solution is correct. And before you simply put it into the post, please review the `solution-verification` tag description to ensure such a post is appropriate for the site.

Answer (score 1):

The problem asks us to prove the existence of a bijection, which is purely dependent on the cardinality structure, i.e. it suffices to show $X/\sim$ is countably infinite.

In fact, $X/\sim$ is infinite, since $(1,n)\not\sim (1,m)$ whenever $m\ne n$, and therefore $X/\sim$ contains an infinite subset $\{[(1,n)]: n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}$, where $[\cdot]$ is the equivalence class of $\cdot$.

On the other hand, $X/\sim$ is at most countable, the reason is as follows: For each equivalence class $A$, select one element $x_A$ in the equivalence class. This gives an injection $f:X/\sim\to X$, $A\mapsto x_A$. Since $X$ is countable, we infer so $X/\sim$ is at most countable.

Therefore $X/\sim$ is countably infinite.

Comment: Type $X/{\sim}$ with `X/{\sim}`. Isn't it better?